# POSTGRES - combine LIKE with exception(E') literal

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

I'm trying to match a certain text that includes a single quote (i.e. '*company's report*...')
normally I would have used the E' literal + ' or double single quotes.
but when it gets to using the LIKE '%' operator, things got complicated.
what is the best approach to match a text with a single quote?

Comment: doubled single quotes work the way I would expect.  Can you explain these perceived complexities?

Comment: when I combined the '%' before and after the string - doubled single quotes raised an -ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Problem"
LINE 7:   ************** LIKE '%'Problem with a credit r...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape single quote with another single quote. Example:

```
WHERE column LIKE 'RSNboim''s'
```

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

> To include a single-quote character within a string constant, write two adjacent single quotes, e.g., `'Dianne''s horse'`. Note that this is not the same as a double-quote character (").

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dollar-quoted String Constants at [Lexical Structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

Your condition should be something like below;

```
select * from atable
where afield like $$Dianne's %$$
```